# Which chess rules cover Internet play?

Tags: online-chess, computer-chess

From FIDE Laws of Chess:

> FIDE Laws of Chess cover over-the-board play.

So, which rules cover Internet chess play?

Answer (score 1):

Each individual site will have their own rules, although many of them will be the same.

I haven't played online in years, so I can't list specifics, but I know the rating systems are different from site to site.

Answer (score 0):

I think FIDE Online Arena rules, but I cannot find them in a written form.